# Как изменить имя файла в mjpg-streamer?

Tags: linux, консоль, opensource, терминал, mjpg

Запускаю:
mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -d /dev/video0 -r  160x120 --fps 5 -q 100" -o "output_http.so -w /www/webcam/ -p 8080" -o "./output_file.so -f /mnt/sda2/mag -d 30000"

По умолчанию имена типа таких:
2016_11_12_20_31_47_picture_000000001.jpg

Можно ли изменить принцип названия файлов?

Comment: думаю что нельзя. только если переписать и собрать самостоятельно

Comment: А чё за бинарник? В каком пакете его искать?